# Linux script incorrect execution

Tags: linux, shell-script

The script is not working correctly. Even if the service is not running, then also the output is ok stating that service is running.

```
#!/bin/sh
is_running=`ps aux | grep -v grep | grep "$1" | wc -l`
echo $is_running
if [ "$is_running" > 0 ]; then
   echo "OK: $1"
   exit 0
else
   echo "Problem: $1 is not running"
   exit 2
Fi
```

Ran it using: `sh scriptname couchbase-server`

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: @Kusalananda: it's not the only problem in this script I think. Even if OP used `-gt 0` that wouldn't help as `$is_running` will be always be greater than 0 because `grep "$1"` will always catch the name of the script.

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk updated in the question. Replacing $1 with servicename also doesn't help.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk `$1` is the first command line argument, not the name of the current script. I don't see how this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Yes but if script will be called like that `./script syslogg` then `ps aux | grep -v grep | grep "$1"` will match `ja       25985  0.0  0.0  11220  2984 pts/22   S+   13:27   0:00 /bin/sh ./script.sh syslogg` unless script is called like that: `./script.sh '[s]yslogg'`

Comment: @myst552: does `couchbase-server` save its PID somewhere, for example in `/var/run`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk The _question_ is why the `if` statement always is true. This is due to the use of the lexicographical ordering test `>` in place of the arithmetic test `-gt`.  This is also the issue in the duplicate.

Comment: @Kusalananda: exactly, correct. This is why I said that this is not *the only problem in this script*. Even if OP replaced `>` with `-gt` it still wouldn't work for them. I just thought it's worth emphasizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always becomes true because of ur command line argument conflicts with the process ur checking. To test the scenario, add sleep 60 in first-line of the script and run it as below

```
sh  script.sh ntpd & ps aux | grep ntpd
[1] 6401
root      6401  0.0  0.0 111940  1208 pts/3    S    16:40   0:00 sh script.sh ntpd
```

you can add `grep -v script.sh` to overcome this issue or just `pidof ntpd | wc -w`

Try this,

```
is_runing=`ps aux | grep -v grep | grep "$1" | grep -v "$(basename $0)" | wc -l`
echo $is_runing
if [ "$is_runing" -gt 0 ]; then
   echo "OK: $1"
   exit 0
else
   echo "Problem: $1 is not running"
   exit 2
fi
```

Comment: Why don't you use `pgrep "$1" >/dev/null`? (or just `pgrep -q "$1"` on BSD systems) This could literally be the complete script, minus informational output.  Your answer does not even _mention_ the use of `>` vs. `-gt`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Obviously... we have various ways... I just tried to answer in OPs way of the scripting ...

Comment: @Kusalananda: `printf 'couchbase-server' | wc -c` show 16, `pgrep` works with process names up to 15 characters. One could use `pgrep -f` but that would also show PID of the calling process.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk My point is that `pgrep` returns an exit status. You don't need its output at all.

Comment: @Kusalananda: it always returns 1 with `pgrep couchbase-server`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk But not with `pgrep -f`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: but with `-f` it's not much better than `ps aux | grep ...` as it will always return PID of the calling script. For example, OP's script could be written like this: https://pastebin.com/x5Fqfvfw. If `couchbase-server` is not running `./script.sh couchbase-server` would still make `pgrep` return 0 inside the script.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk So, back to my original comment. _This whole script_ could be replaced by `pgrep -f couchbase-server`. You don't need this script to tell you that it's running, Or, you could have a shell function: `isrunning () { pgrep -f "$1" >/dev/null; }` and then use it as `isrunning couchbase-server && echo yes`.  Or, if you want to have a _simple_ fix, test with `-gt 1`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: yes, the script could be replaced by a single `pgrep` unless the snippet of code that OP showed in the question is a part of bigger logic that is happening in the script that has to accept program name as an argument but we don't know that.